# Show blog post excerpt with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show the `excerpts` from blog posts. I am able to do this with `php` and `mysql`. However, I am wondering if there is a more 'friendly' way of doing this within the Laravel framework.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your PHP code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it using the method `words`

Default is:

```
 words($value,$words = 100, $end='...');
```

You can implement it like this

```
Str::words($post->body);

Str::words($post->body,10); //will show first 10 words
```

Incase of any error like Str class not found use the following statement

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Answer (score 15):

Sorry I am very late but hope that it will help someone:

Using it like this may throw "Class 'Str' not found error":

```
Str::words($post->body,10);
```

**Use along with complete namespace, like this:**

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::words($post->body, 10);
```

**OR with dots:**

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::words($post->body, 10,'...');
```

OR register the function as Facade in **config/app.php**, try adding it like this way:

```
'aliases' => [
...
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
...
]
```

And then use **Str::** any where!, and hence you are free you use:
Str::words($post->body,10);

**Need short and neat solution, just use Laravel's [str_limit()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-limit) helper function:**

```
str_limit($post->body, 10);
```

**OR**

```
str_limit($post->body, 10,'...');
```

Comment: Thank You So much for Help.

Comment: You Welcome @ViperTecPro

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_limit` easily.

Inside the PHP files:

```
str_limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...')
```

Inside the [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) files:

```
{{ str_limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...') }}
```

I saw that this is available from version [4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#strings) to [5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-limit)

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Some answers above mentioned Str class which is removed from laravel core and moved to new helpers package. As mentioned in Laravel v6.x upgrade guide.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers

"All `str_` and `array_` helpers have been moved to the new `laravel/helpers` Composer package and removed from the framework. If desired, you may update all calls to these helpers to use the `Illuminate\Support\Str` and `Illuminate\Support\Arr` classes. Alternatively, you can add the new laravel/helpers package to your application to continue using these helpers:"

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Simply install it via Composer and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Illuminate\Support\Str` class with `Str::limit($string, $limit, $end)`, for example:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Str;
/*...*/
Str::limit($myString, 50, '>>>');
```